# How to remove the last comma in every div?

Tags: jquery

How to remove the last comma in every div ?

Game, Play, Book,

Boy, Girl, Cat,

Team, Ball, Sport,

***to***

Game, Book

Boy, Girl

Team, Ball

***HTML:***

```
<div class="tags"><a href="#">Game</a>, <a href="#">Play</a>, <a href="#">Books</a>, </div>
<div class="tags"><a href="#">Boy</a>, <a href="#">Girl</a>, <a href="#">Cat</a>, </div>
<div class="tags"><a href="#">Team</a>, <a href="#">Ball</a>, <a href="#">Sport</a>, </div>
```

Comment: I'm going to assume the data in your divs is a result of a loop that each item has a `,` at the end? Might be the best place to fix this inside of the loop itself. If in a for statement, then test to see if it's the last iteration of the loop (ie: `if (i < count -1)`) and if not print a `,` after each item. This way the last one will never have the `,` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$('.tags').each(function(){
 var xContents = $(this).contents();
 xContents[xContents.length - 1].nodeValue = "";
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Yk3SR/)

Comment: How to implement this in a WordPress page? Please consider that I'm new to JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to achieve this.

```
$('div.tags').each(function(){
    str = $(this).html();
    var parts = str.split(",");
    parts.pop();
    $(this).html(parts.join(','));
});
```

You can see a demo here in <kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arulmr/y8ZSm/)**</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

```
$('.tags').each(function(){
   var txt = $(this).html().trim().slice(0,-1);
   $(this).html(txt);
});
```